# Is there a way to combine a pydantic and SQLite model into one class?

Tags: python, sqlite, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using `fastapi` and `SQLite` to make a simple API that can write to a database.

The `pydantic` model (`Component` class in `main.py`) is almost identical to the `SQLite` one (`Component` class in `models.py`). These two models could end up having many more properties. Each added property adds a line of duplicated code to the `create` and `update` methods that exists only to copy data from one model to the other. It seems like there must be a more elegant way to do this (sharing a model, multiple inheritance?) rather than defining two nearly identical classes and copying individual properties line by line multiple times.

### models.py

A simple `SQLite` model:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from database import Base

class Component(Base):
    __tablename__ = "components"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
    author = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)
```

### main.py

I use `fastapi` and `pydantic` to define a basic CRUD API in a `main.py`. I've included only two of the operations:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from database import engine, SessionLocal
import models

app = FastAPI()

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

def get_db():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

class Component(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(min_length=1)
    author: str = Field(min_length=1, max_length=100)
    description: str = Field(min_length=1, max_length=100)

@app.post("/")
def create_component(component: Component, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    c = models.Component()
    c.name = component.name
    c.author = component.author
    c.description = component.description
    db.add(c)
    db.commit()
    return component

@app.put("/{component_id}")
def update_component(component_id: int, component: Component, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    c.name = component.name
    c.author = component.author
    c.description = component.description

    db.add(c)
    db.commit()
    return component
```

Comment: [The FastAPI tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-data) shows that using `.dict()` simplifies the creation of models from schemas. Keeping schemas and models independent seems in my opinion a good design choice because they have different resposibilities.

Comment: [SQLModel from the same author as FastAPI is an attempt to limit duplication between those two layers](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/) - it's a way to integrate a layer between SQLAlchemy and your Pydantic models. You might want to look at whether it satisfies your needs.

Comment: @MatsLindh this is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for!